# Keras GridSearchCV: Train and Validation Accuracy high but low test accuracy? (SOLVED, BUT WITH A NEW DOUBT IN CV) )

Tags: cross-validation, keras

CODE SNIPPET

Binary classification problem where train_data : N X H X W X F
train_labels: N X 1

```
train_classes =to_categorical(train_labels)
test_classes =to_categorical(test_labels)


score = {'AUC': 'roc_auc', 'Accuracy': make_scorer(accuracy_score)}
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):

    grid =  GridSearchCV(estimator = kerasmodel, param_grid = p, cv = 4, scoring= score,refit = 'AUC',verbose = 5)

    grid_result = (grid.fit(train_data, train_classes,shuffle = 'true'))

    print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, 
    grid_result.best_params_))

    bestmodel = grid.best_estimator_

    preds = model.predict_proba(test_data)
    auc = roc_auc_score(test_classes, preds)
    acc = accuracy_score(test_classes[:,1], (preds[:,0]<preds[:,1])*1)

    preds2 = model.predict(test_data)
    auc2 = roc_auc_score(test_labels,preds2)
```

LAST LAYERS OF MODEL SNIPPET

```
    Dense(10, activation = activation),
    Dense(2, activation ='softmax')
```

Loss is categorical_crossentropy

```
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer(lr=lr),
                              loss = loss,
                              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

The train and validation(after each epoch) accuracy would be around 90%, validation AUC after 1 epoch = 90 , but test accuracy would be low around 70% and test AUC even more low = 50 ?  What would be the issue here?

**EDIT** : FOUND WHERE THE ISSUE WAS. TRAINING DATA CONTAINED REPITIONS.

But now I'm posed with a new question. How do I perform training on imbalanced data and also perform CV?

Comment: It’s impossible to diagnose your issues without access to runnable code and data. It sounds like maybe your test data is either nonrandomly selected or preprocessed incorrectly.

Comment: Yes I understand..but I have restrictions on sharing it. I have checked the test data and have even did a run on replacing a part of training data with the test data and making the replaced part as test, the issue still occurs. I'm skeptical about the prediction after fitting part, but I have done the prediction on train data and that result was as expected. So I don't t really understand what's going on?

Comment: Oh good god...there is resampling in the training data and hence repetition of data. So it really can't be split during CV. And hence the CV accuracies were sky high. I had not written the training data so I was not aware. Anyways, could anyone suggest there how could I perform CV otherwise ? The data is highly imbalanced with a ratio of 1:4.

Comment: Solved, Found the answer here - https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32071/how-to-set-class-weight-for-imbalanced-classes-in-kerasclassifier-while-it-is-us